# How to make a sample that shows the 'Props are overwritten when re-rendering' anti pattern

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mutation, anti-patterns, vue-props

I would like to be convinced that '[Props are overwritten when re-rendering](https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly/)' is an [anti pattern](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-mutating-props.html).

```
const MyButton = Vue.extend({
  props: {
    obj: {}
  },
  template:
    "<button @click=\"obj.text = 'Value'+Math.round(Math.random()*100)\">Change text in child ({{obj.text}})</button>"
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    obj: { text: "Value2" }
  },
  components: {
    MyButton
  },
  template: `
<div>
  <Button @click='obj.text = "Value"+Math.round(Math.random()*100)'>Change text in parent ({{obj.text}})</Button><br>
  <MyButton :obj='obj'/>  Pressing here 'mutate' the prop. It is an anti-pattern (Props are overwritten when re-rendering). But it seems to work just fine, how to change this sample so it shows the anti-pattern problem? (https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-mutating-props.html)
</div>`
});
```

UPDATED Codepen:
https://codepen.io/SVSMITH/pen/LYrXRzW

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are actually not mutating the prop, because what you send in to the child is a reference to an object. This reference stays the same. See what happens if you change the template code in your child to:

```
"<button @click=\"obj = {}\">Change text in child ({{obj.text}})</button>"
```

Then you will see that the prop is overwritten and the value of the child differs from that in the parent. When the parent updates the value, the updated value in the child will be overwritten. Which can cause serious and hard to find bugs. Therefore use [emit](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) in the child to update the value in the parent, which will update the child value through the prop.

If you have a lot of these props and emits, you should look into using a store like [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks Gabe. So updating properties (eg. text) on a props (eg. obj) in a child component is not an anti-pattern? I have updated the codepen to better illustrate the situation, it might help other to (also) better understand it.

Comment: I would only do that if it is very clear where the update is taking place. If it is getting more complex, like multiple children or grandchildren editing the same object, I would opt for a more transparant solution.

Comment: Thanks for input. In my case, the parent component has e.g. a customer object (that extends a super class of mine). The child component is a reusable component and should be used by many components (e.g. customer, supplier, product etc.). The child component only operate on properties on the super class and the logic here is only located in the child component. The parent does not really care. In that way I just add the child component to eg. a customer, supplier or product component and no further code is not needed in the parent component. I hope it make sense :-)

Comment: Yeah makes sense, and then I would just use it that way.